# How to stream audio with Jquery/Php

Tags: php, jquery, audio, http-headers

I currently have an mp3 player I built with jquery. I wanted to know if there is a quicker way I can get the mp3 file and play it to the user, or "Stream" it, like how pandora does. This is how I get the Song data:

```
    song = document.createElement('audio');
    source = document.createElement("source");
    song.appendChild(source);
    source.setAttribute("type", "audio/mpeg");
    source.src = "getMp3.php";
```

The getMp3.php file looks like this:

```
    $fileName = "Song.mp3";
    $file = "/Music/".$fileName;
    $mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";
    $shortlen = filesize($file)-1;

    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    $etag = md5(serialize(fstat($fp)));
    fclose($fp);

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Content-type: '.$mime_type);
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$shortlen.'/'.filesize($file));
    header('Etag: '.$etag);
    readfile($file);
```

Most of the time, it takes about 10 seconds to load the file. This can be longer depending on how big the file is, but 10 is usually the average. I also tried only sending part of the mp3 file, but it still takes about 10 seconds even if the mp3 is 10 seconds, or 3 minutes. Is there any way to load/ play the song quicker?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script will display the page after loading the whole music file, so it costs mush.

To play music on web on stream, there are two ways to do that:

1. Flash player: there are thousands of JavaScript/jQuery music players which by you can Google.
2. HTML 5 `<audio>` tag: `<audio src="song.mp3" controls="controls"/>`

Comment: I read that flash can stream the mp3, but I'd rather try an HTML5 solution, if I can find one. And I can't just set the src as the song name because I need it to be dynamic, and I don't want to give the user a direct path to the file.

Comment: If you need to generate song path dynamicly, you can use jquey ajax `.get` method to  set the `src` asynchronously. But if you don't want user to get the path of file **from source code**, you can use javascript to set `src` at runtime, and do some encryption/decryption work on that.